# Placement of clearRect() in canvas (with text animation)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am a newbie in HTML5 canvas and made a simple text animation.

However I am unable to clear the previously drawn text when animation is in process. The text look dragged. Please find the code link below for clear picture. Click on animate button to see the animation.

```
function drawTextOnCanvas(
can,
  ctx,
  text,
  font,
  backColor,
  textColor,
  maxWidth,
  startingx,
  startingy,
  spacing
) {
  var linesArray = getLines(ctx, text, maxWidth);
  ctx.save();

  for (var i = 0; i < linesArray.length; i++) {

    drawTextBG(
    can,
      ctx,
      linesArray[i],
      font,
      backColor,
      textColor,
      startingx,
      startingy
    );

    // ctx.fillText(linesArray[i], startingx, startingy);
    /* startingx += spacing; */
    startingy += spacing; // Remove this if you want everthing in line
  }
  ctx.restore();
}

function getLines(ctx, text, maxWidth) {
  // Enter maxWidth depending on the resolution and canvas dimensions
  var words = text.split(" ");
  var lines = [];
  var currentLine = words[0];
    ctx.font = "54px bolder Arial"
  for (var i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
    var word = words[i];
    var width = ctx.measureText(currentLine + " " + word).width;
    if (width < maxWidth) {
      currentLine += " " + word;
    } else {
      lines.push(currentLine);
      currentLine = word;
    }
  }
  lines.push(currentLine);
  return lines;
}

function drawTextBG(can,ctx, txt, font, backColor, textColor, x, y) {
  /// set font
  console.log(txt)
  x= -300;
  let speed = 15;
  let distance = 0;
   var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var interval = setInterval(function() {

    if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 1000) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

  if (distance >= 600) {
    distance = 0;
    // clearInterval(interval);
    x = canv.width / 2;
  }

    distance += speed;

    animateText(can,ctx, txt, font, backColor, textColor, x + distance, y);

  }, 33);


}



function animateText(can,ctx, txt, font, backColor, textColor, x, y) {

  ctx.font = font;
  /// draw text from top - makes life easier at the moment
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  /// color for background
  ctx.fillStyle = backColor;
  /// get width of text

  var width = ctx.measureText(txt).width;
  /// draw background rect assuming height of font
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, parseInt(font, 10));
  /// text color
  ctx.fillStyle = textColor;
  /// draw text on top
  ctx.fillText(txt, x, y);

}
```

This is the ***[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anish_jana/pg7mhory/87/)***

Help me in getting perfect animation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not make much out of your code, ended up refactoring all.

Hopefully, this sends you on the right direction

```js
class Text {
  constructor(txt, font, backColor, textColor, x, y, speed) {
    this.txt = txt;
    this.font = font;
    this.backColor = backColor;
    this.textColor = textColor;
    this.initX = x;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = speed;
  }
  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.font = this.font;
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.fillStyle = this.backColor;

    var width = ctx.measureText(this.txt).width;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, width, parseInt(this.font, 10));
    ctx.fillStyle = this.textColor;
    ctx.fillText(this.txt, this.x, this.y);
    this.x -= this.speed ;
    if (this.x < -width)
      this.x = this.initX
  }
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

initX = canvas.width
dogs = new Text("Dogs are cute animals", "20px Arial", "#f50", "#000", initX, 20, 1)
cats = new Text("Cats say Miauu", "22px Arial", "#000", "#0F0", initX, 50, 0.5)
hello = new Text("HELLO", "12px Arial", "#F00", "#FF0", initX, 80, 3)

setInterval(draw, 20)

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  dogs.draw(ctx)
  cats.draw(ctx)
  hello.draw(ctx)
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=220 height=100></canvas>
```

Should be all clear, let me know if there is anything that confuses you